# Poor CPU Frequency on HP Laptop running Kubuntu

Tags: performance, cpu, intel, kubuntu

After using Windows my hole life, i wanted to try a new operating system. I settled on Kubuntu since I liked the design and the easy usability of Ubuntu from a newbie perspective. While using it for browsing I haven't noticed any problems. However when I try to load some CPU intensive tasks I can feel a significant performance hit compared to windows.
But first of all my configuration:
I'm running a HP Probook 470 G5 with a [Intel i7 8550u](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) which should be capable of 1.8GHz on all cores and 3.7GHz burst.
However when I load the CPU (e.g a stresstest) it will only run at 1.2GHz (output from i7z)
[image]
As you can also see in the picture the CPU isn't thermal throttling.
As soon as I reduce the load the clockspeeds return to "normal"
[image]
I also issued `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance` to change the CPU profile to performance. This didn't show any difference in clock speed under load. 
Also note that I'm running all test with plugged in power cord. Furthermore no advanced power manager should be running, but you can prove me wrong ;)
If you need any more information I will add them as soon as possible.
I assume it has something to do with the general power management of the system, but I can be wrong. Hopefully we can find a solution. Otherwise I will need to change back to windows ;(

The Kernel Version is 5.8.0-44-generic

Edit: I noticed that the temps spike (at least s-tui show that) on the CPU die itself, then the CPU throttles and never recovers.
Edit: Turning the CPU frequency down to 2GHz result in a way longer CPU burst, but only at 2 GHz. This may indicate that it's in fact a thermal issue. However I would consider 60°C as more than adequate cooling.

Comment: I will be honest and frank: I dislike Kubuntu, and I prefer older version of kernel 5.4.xxx. I would try Linux Mint Cinnamon, I also have Kaby Lake, but not 8th revision, just 7th gen. What could you lose by trying it out(?) here's link: https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=284

Comment: I would rather prefer using Kubuntu instead of Mint. Why do you think Mint is better than Ubuntu since Mint is based on Ubuntu?

Comment: KDE is _dead_ sort of speak. Only my opinion. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: what is the exact command you use for the stress test most Intel chips with on board graphics have a much slower graphics max frequency  i forget the exact name they call it but it is usually considerably slower then the base frequency so if the stress test is gpu heavy you should expect a lower frequency

Comment: I'm not stress testing my GPU nor the integrated GPU, I'm stress testing my CPU

Comment: What command are you running to stress it.

Comment: I'm using the stress package with `stress --cpu 6`

Comment: I tried using Linux Mint (newest Version as of today), Manjaro (which is based on Arch so should have newest kernel), and Kubuntu 18.04. None of these OS could fix the issue. -> Linux Experiment ended -> returning back to windows. If anyone encounters a fix, I'll be more than happy to retry.

Answer (score 0):

Comming from another account, since I created this question with a guest account. In a random talk yesterday I mentioned my poor Linux experience. The one listening however had the same issue and pointed me to this
[github repo](https://github.com/erpalma/throttled) which provides a solution for this problem. Hopefully this is helpful for others.